# According to Adorno, does the "truth content" of art refer?

Tags: plato, aesthetics, language, hegel, adorno

[image]

- Adorno and the Political, By Espen Hammer

In this negation, by truth content, is it a form of referentiality?

Which *may* be to ask whether truth content is linguistic, in this action of negation.

Comment: On “truth content” (*Wahrheitsgehalt*), see [Adorno's Aesthetic Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/adorno/#4): "The artwork has an internal truth content to the extent that the artwork's import can be found internally and externally either true or false. Such truth content is not a metaphysical idea or essence hovering outside the artwork. But neither is it a merely human construct. It is historical but not arbitrary; nonpropositional, yet calling for propositional claims to be made about it [...]"

Comment: are you saying that it is or isn't referential ?

Comment: Itb is clearly "non-referential": "one must temporarily suspend standard theories about the nature of truth (whether as correspondence, coherence, or pragmatic success) and allow for artistic truth to be dialectical, disclosive, and nonpropositional."

Comment: i'm not sure it's clearly that, or i wouldn't have asked. i'm familiar with what you quote

Comment: i don't know at all, but i don't *think* that only propositions can refer.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA hey just to say, that i was chatting someone really into aesthetics, and they said that, for adorno, truth content (whatever utopian role it has to play) is separate from critique, the former of which is interior to the work, even if it is unfolded via its relation to what is critiqued... as such, any political sense it has does not make truth content "about" the political